# Making values inside column clickable (fires click_event)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid and I want to make the values in the first column "clickable" so that they fire a click event. The values in this first column are populated from a sql server query.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Below is my grid:

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="HSMGrid"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                DataKeyNames="Status"
                OnRowCommand="grdvwSearchDepositTransaction_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdSearch_RowDataBound" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                CssClass="grid" Width="550">
                <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.groupID" HeaderText="BatchID" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.bankNumber" HeaderText="Bank" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.branchNumber" HeaderText="Branch" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.cashInTicketAmount" HeaderText="Cash-In Ticket Amount" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.createdBy" HeaderText="Created By" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransactionGroupsEntry.dateCreated" HeaderText="Date Created" ItemStyle-CssClass="mediumColumn columnCenter" />
                        </Columns>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <span style="font-weight: bold;">No Transactions have been entered</span>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Edit:: 
This is what I currently have following the advise of the first answer: 
[image]

Comment: click event on client or on server?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter server

Comment: See if this helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to convert the first column into a template field.  The template field's ItemTemplate would then contain a server side control (i.e LinkButton).  This control could then have a server side OnClick event attached to it that would handle the server side logic.  Below is an example:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BatchID">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnBatchId" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TransactionGroupsEntry.groupID") %>' OnClick="btnBatchId_Click" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TransactionGroupsEntry.groupID") %>' />
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

In your code behind file your click event could look like the below example.  I have added the ability to parse out/get at the id that is associated to the LinkButton:

```
 protected void btnBatchId_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      var linkButton = sender as LinkButton;
      if (linkButton != null) {
           var batchId = 0;
           if (int.TryParse(linkButton.CommandArgument, out batchId)) {
                // batchId variable should contain a valid integer value
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Please check my edit in my main post I think you're onto something

Comment: Use a LinkButton instead of button if it should be text.

Comment: Correct, if this needs to appear as text or a clickable link, then I would also suggest a LinkButton rather than a Button.  My sample code was just for the purposes of providing an example.  See my update above to the answer posted.

Comment: AWESOME. Thank you so much guys I'm going to have to research databinder/binding? Never knew about this before. :\

Now I just got to figure out how to parse that value from the button clicked.

Comment: I have added an example to access the batchId value that was assigned to the CommandArgument parameter of the LinkButton.